# Azure event hubs python library

Tags: python, django, azure

I'm trying to get the [Azure event hubs python module](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python) to work.
I've followed the instructions in the readme; which is mostly just "install Proto-c".
Everything installs without any problems but when I try to run the receiver I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "recv.py", line 16, in
>   
>       from eventhubs import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset   File "/home/garr/Workspace/Bodaytrak/webhost/azure-event-hubs/eventhubs/**init**.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from proton import DELEGATED, Url, timestamp, generate_uuid, utf82unicode ImportError: No module named proton

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

TL:DR, Ignore the given instructions and just install Proton via pip

> pip install python-qpid-proton

It looks like following the installation instructions in the github repo doesn't give you the correct bindings, and I couldn't figure out a way to make it work.